# MediaPlayer - Play mp3 files serially

Tags: android, media-player

I have a String, for example "abcde", and want to spell each letter of it through MediaPlayer. Suppose it's under sdcard folder, a.mp3, b.mp3 etc.  I use:

```
String s = "abcde";
int length = s.length(); //5
int i = 1;
char current_char = 'a';

mp = new MediaPlayer();
String filePath = "/sdcard/" + current_char + ".mp3";
mp.setDataSource(filePath);
mp.prepare();
mp.start(); //a is played

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    if (i < length) {
        current_char = s.charAt(i);
        i++;

        mp.release();
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        filePath = "/sdcard/" + current_char + ".mp3";
        mp.setDataSource(filePath);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

However this only causes letter "a"to be played only. Can't find what's wrong, how can I make it so all the letters are played? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the OnCompletionListener after you call the MediaPlayer.start().

You are probably, missing the onCompletion event.

Try to set the listener just after the object instatiation, like this:

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    if (i < length) {
        current_char = s.charAt(i);
        i++;

        mp.release();
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        filePath = "/sdcard/" + current_char + ".mp3";
        mp.setDataSource(filePath);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
       }
    }
});
mp.setDataSource(filePath);
mp.prepare();
mp.start(); //a is played
```